# Matlab optional input and output arguments in a function

Tags: matlab, function

I am writing a function and I need some help.
This is my function:

```
function [varargout] = myfunc(x, y, z, optional)
```

There are two possible outputs: A and B. By setting the compulsory input variables (x,y,z), you get A. If you also set the optional argument, you should get A and B as well. 
So, this is the way I am trying to do it:

```
if (nargin == 4)
varargout{1} = A;
varargout{2} = B;
else
varargout{1} = A;
end
```

This is not working... Where am I making the mistake?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "This is not working."  Could you please be more specific and edit any error messages into your question?

Comment: Also, you do have a leading `function` keyword before `[varargout]` in your actual file, correct?

Comment: Yes, I do, I forgot to write it

Comment: Hi Troy, the error message I get is: "Output argument "varargout{2}" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "myfunc"."

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with it. The only problem will come if you attempt:

```
[a,b] = myfunc(1,2,3)
```

in which case your function will complain that you're trying to assign to a second variable that hasn't been defined. So you need to have some more input / output checking (e.g. via `nargout`) and act accordingly. (i.e. either specify a custom error, or return `b=[]`, etc.

PS. I'm assuming your function is defined something like:

```
function varargout = myfunc(x, y, z, optional)
  if (nargin == 4); varargout{1} = 1; varargout{2} = 2;
  else              varargout{1} = 1;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two outputs with varargout. Try this:

```
[A,varargout] = myfunc(x, y, z, optional)
```

and

```
if (nargin > 3)
    varargout{1} = B;
end
```

Comment: Thank you freude. I tried it, but I get this message: "Not enough input arguments." when I set only 3 input variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this code:

1. First, you haven't put the keyword "function" before declaring
   myfunc.
2. Second, optional is set as the 4th argument. However, this way you
   cannot include more than 4 arguments.
3. Third, you have to be careful with varargout, since it increases the
   number of output argument, but it doesn't change the first one
   (which is always equal to one).

I don't know which of the above was your main concern, however, the following code should be working:

```
function varargout = myfunc2(x, y, z, varargin)
    if nargin == 4    
        varargout{1} = 1; % where A=1 and B = 2
        varargout{2} = 2;
    else
        varargout{1} = 1;
    end
end
```

Please have a look to the attached links for more details about varargin and varargout:

1. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html
2. http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html

Comment: Thank you merch. The problem is that the optional input argument is a number and, when set, the function  looks for the values of the first output (A) that are greater than it. However, `varargin` is a cell array, so I get an error message. I have tried with the exist function as well, but it is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! I'll post here the solution, it could be useful for others. Thank you all!

```
function [A, varargout] = myfunc(x, y, z, optional)

A = somefunction(x,y,z)

if nargout == 2 && nargin == 4
i = find(A > optional); 
B = somefunction(A,i);
varargout{1} = B;
end
```

In this way, you have an optional output associated to an optional input variable. It works :)